# Move programatically added TextView back and forth between layouts onClick

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have this `FlowLayout` where I have a set of `TextView`'s which I build programatically. After getting the wanted names, I create a `TextView` for each name inside the layout.
What I want to do, if I click on the `TextView`, I want to move it into another layout. I manage to do that but I also want to move it back. I could also do that until I program it to, but I can't program it to be like a infinite loop.

This is a piece of code which will make you understand better what I'm talking about hopefully.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FlowLayoutTextView));
        tv.setText("Test");
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tvSelected = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FlowLayoutTextView));
                tvSelected.setText(tv.getText().toString());
                tvSelected.setLayoutParams(params);
                tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                filteredLayout.addView(tvSelected);
            }
        });
        unfilteredLayout.addView(tv);
```

Is it possible to make it work? Thanks.

LE: As you can see in the `onClickListener` event of the `TextView`, I create the other `TextView` I add in the other layout, to move it back I could also add an `onClickListener` event to this `TextView` but this is not the solution.

Comment: Do you remove the textview from one layout?

Comment: I just set its visibility to GONE. The piece of code i added is what I actually done. I am thinking about it but I don't know how to aproach it.

Comment: remove it from one layout and add it to another

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
boolean isInFilterLayout = false; //Class variable
TextView tv = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),    R.style.FlowLayoutTextView));
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isInFilterLayout){
               filteredLayout.remove(tv);
               unfilteredLayout.addView(tv);
               isInFilterLayout = false;
            }else{
               unfilteredLayout.remove(tv);
               filteredLayout.addView(tv);
               isInFilterLayout = true;
            }

        }
    });
    unfilteredLayout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: That's great, thank you :) the problem is I have an unknown number of this `TextView`s so I have to have a `boolean` for each of them but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: you could set tag to textview as well. tv.setTag(true) check the value